# Proving a generalization of Euler's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I'm working through Niven's book on Number Theory and I'm having trouble with this question:

Prove that, for any integer $a$, $a^m \equiv a^{m-\phi(m)}$ (mod $m$). I can easily figure it out in the case where $(a,m) = 1$, but I'm having trouble in the case that they're not relatively prime.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Yes; this question is in the section on CRT, so I figured I might have to use that. -- but would welcome some hint on how to start.

Comment: Recall that the CRT says that given some set of congruences mod pairwise coprime numbers, there is a unique solution mod the product of these. Try to apply this to the factorization of $m$ into prime powers.

Comment: So something like $x\equiv a^{m-\phi(m)}$ (mod $p_i^{e_i}$), where $m = \prod p_i^{e_i}$?

Comment: Right. Can you show that $a^m$ is a solution to that?

Comment: I'm trying to use the construction of the solution the book used in the proof of the CRT. But how would I find the inverse of $\frac{m}{p_i^{e_i}}$ mod ${p_i^{e_i}}$?

Comment: You don't need this. You just need to use that if some $x$ satisfies all those congruences, then any other solution will be congruenct to $x$ mod $m$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out how to show $a^m$ is a solution to that. It doesn't seem obvious that $p_i^{e_i} | a^m(1 - a^{-\phi(m)})$.

Comment: Split it into two cases depending on whether $p_i$ divides $a$ or not. Can you show it in one of those?

Comment: Ah, I think I see. And in the other case, they are relatively prime, which I've already figured out. Thank you very much for your help!